# Pass redirect through to visitor?

Tags: cloudflare-workers

When my worker encounters a redirect from origin it follows it and returns the content rather than passing the redirect on to the visitor. Does anyone know how to force the worker to respond with the same redirect it receives from origin?

This is in conjunction with a proxy.

`http://server.one/proxy-path/old-directory/` request is sent to `http://server.two/old-directory/` which responds with a 301 to /new-directory/. The end result should be that the visitor is sent to `http://server.one/proxy-path/new-directory/` but what happens is that the worker follows the redirect and serves up the content from /new-directory/ under the `/proxy-path/old-directory/` path.

Hopefully this made sense. Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 3):

Following redirects is the default behavior of `fetch()`. You can override it like:

```
fetch(url, {redirect: "manual"})
```

But there may be a deeper problem with your script. Normally, the incoming `event.request` already has the `redirect = "manual"` property set, so if you were to pass `event.request` directly to `fetch()`, then you would get the behavior you want. If you are seeing redirects being automatically followed, that suggests that you are *not* passing the original request object and, moreover, you have dropped some of the original request's properties.

This commonly happens when people write code like:

```
// INCORRECT: Loses request properties and headers!
let newUrl = rewriteUrl(event.request.url);
event.respondWith(fetch(newUrl));
```

Sometimes people realize that this loses the headers, so they try to add them back like:

```
// STILL INCORRECT: Loses request properties other than headers!
let newUrl = rewriteUrl(event.request.url);
event.respondWith(fetch(newUrl, {headers: event.request.headers}));
```

The *correct* thing to do is to pass the whole `request` object as the second parameter to `fetch()`, like:

```
// CORRECT
let newUrl = rewriteUrl(event.request.url);
event.respondWith(fetch(newUrl, event.request));
```

This way, all of the request's properties, including `redirect`, `method`, `body`, etc., get copied over.

Note that if you want to modify the URL *and* the headers, you need to do two steps:

```
let newUrl = rewriteUrl(event.request.url);
let newHeaders = rewriteHeaders(event.request.headers);
// Create a new Request object with the new headers.
let newRequest = new Request(event.request, {headers: newHeaders});
// Fetch the new URL using the new Request object.
event.respondWith(fetch(newUrl, newRequest));
```

Alternatively, you can take advantage of the fact that a Request object you created yourself (as opposed to the one you received on the event) is mutable:

```
let newUrl = rewriteUrl(event.request.url);
// Create a new Request object with modified URL.
let newRequest = new Request(newUrl, event.request);
// Modify the headers directly on this object.
newRequest.headers.set("X-Foo", "Bar");
// Forward it on.
event.respondWith(fetch(newRequest));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I asked the question to soon. Based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch I see that I can add `redirect: 'manual'` to the proxy request which returns the redirect response I expected.